# Razor .net core 3.1 with IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, identityserver4, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I know this subject was discussed in different posts but I didn't find the answer to my problem.

I'm doing a POC with .net core 3.1 and IdentityServer4.

For the moment I have a Auth server with IdentityServer4 and a console application in .net core. This combination works and I have no problem.

The next step was to do a blank website to see how the authentication works with IdentityServer4. I've added a client in my Auth server and did the website too and when I try to access a page with a model [Authorize] I have the message :.

> Sorry, there was an error : invalid_scope
>
> Invalid scope

Here is where I set clients :

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "consoleappclient",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "bxsecurityapi" }
            },
             // OpenID Connect implicit flow client (MVC)
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "razorappclient",
                ClientName = "Razor Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5005/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5005/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And here is my client :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.Scope.Add("openid");

                options.ClientId = "razorappclient";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Identity Server logs will give you which scope it is expecting.

Comment: @Gobelet Did you try it all on http? Asking cause I did replicate your POC [here](https://github.com/nahidf/IdentityServer4-adventures/tree/master/src/RazorClient) its all working fine, in my case I changed `Privacy` view to be protected. I guess easiest is to try on http and if you have same issue, compare your code with mine. If issue was just on https, we would need to check the logs for more details then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad ...

I had that line in my Auth server :

```
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetApiResources())
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
```

and the correct thing is ...

```
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
```

What I posted here was good in fact. 
Really good idea for the log file. It wasn't implemented yet but it was really easy and helped me a lot.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Invalid scope related to your scope name, make sure your defined scope correctly matches with the client one. correctly you are allowing the `bxsecurityapi` or `OpenId` scope which is not matched with the client one's `openid`!

Edited:
So the problem is your standard scope, 
try this one :

```
options.Scope.Add("openid profile email");
```

Or Try to add a new scope name to your server-side application :

```
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "razorappclient",
            ClientName = "Razor Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

            RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5005/signin-oidc" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5005/signout-callback-oidc" },

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                "openIdTest",
            }
        }
```

And then use it in your client-side application, it should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to replace "openid" by "OpenId" but I still have the same issue.
I wanted to give access to my consoleapp to a specific API with the scope "bxsecurityapi" and forbid that API to webapp client

Answer (score 0):

bxsecurityapi this should also be added as scope in clients. Then only  identity server will respond. Fore details check identityserver4 documentation.there is well described description.

Comment: It means I can't give access my console app to a specific  API  and forbid that API to another client ?

Comment: Can you share your resource configuration of identity server 4?